# Spotting memory vulnerabilities in my code using C

Tags: c, security, memory

I am suppose to spot memory vulnerabilities in this particular function of C program, I am not too sure as i think the program does accounts for integer overflows, can anyone help me? thanks!

```
char* StringEncryptor(char *input, char *key) {
    size_t len = strlen(input);
    char *encrypted = malloc(len + 4);
    unsigned int i;  

    for(i = len; i != 0; i--) { //XOR with a key;

        *(encrypted + i + 4)= *(input + i) ^ (key[i % 8]);

    }

    *(size_t *)(encrypted) = len;

    return encrypted;
}
```

Comment: Would you be interested in help according to the compromise described here? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Please define a "memory vulnerability". Memory leak? Attackable via maliciously filled memory? Misuseable via unintentionally writing to out of scope memory?

Comment: The code looks vulnerable to overwrites when run on a machine where `sizeof(size_t) != 4` — e.g. 64-bit systems on Unix.  (The final assignment would overwrite the first 4 bytes of the encrypted string.)  The code doesn't test the length of the key; it seems to assume it is at least 8.  Maybe it can't test it if the key could hold null bytes. It could be argued that it doesn't check either argument for validity — however, I probably would use just `assert(input != NULL && key != NULL);` rather than trying to handle the error.  If some programmer abuses the function, a crash is a kindness.

Comment: Without additional explanation and without even any feedback on Jonathans versy plausible comment, your question remains a mystery. I.e. it is unclear what you are asking about, if nothing triggers any comment.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hi, i guess you can say it somewhat falls under the realm of homework. I adapted this function from an open source for my software project and my tutor briefly mentioned there were at least 2 vulnerabilities for attacks but didnt specify what kind. I researched a bit and think it should be something to do with memory overflow but i wasnt sure as it doesnt seem to be a buffer or integer overflow...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler oh right, i didnt consider the sizeof(size_t) in different OSes. As for the key, in my program, it will always be initialized to a random value internally (not reliant on user input), so I probably didnt expect to check for a null value. Is there a case where size_t and unsigned int would occupy different memory size, ie size_t is 8 bytes and unsigned int would be 4 bytes? im just considering if there will be a problem when declaring i = len

Comment: 64-bit Unix systems have `size_t` at 8 and `unsigned int` at 4.  Consider `uint32_t` from `<stdint.h>` if you want a fixed size and will not need to handle messages more than 4 GiB.

Comment: `*(size_t *)(encrypted) = len` is a undefined behavior.  It is assuming that encrypted is sufficiently aligned for a size_t.  See c11 section 6.3.2.3.7.